# Can you view message bodies using 'HAT' in BizTalk 2006?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2006

So I need to view the message body of a message that is entering an orchestration in BizTalk 2006, because there is no admin console tracking, i'm trying to use Health and Activity Tracking' I can see the orchestration in the query results but when I right click on the cell and show the message flow, it show me the details of the inputted message into the orchestration but from what I can see it doesn't allow me to view the message body, am I missing something or is there another way to view the body in 2006?

Thanks,
Kyle.

Comment: Is Message Body Tracking enabled on the Port/Orchestration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - I found the answer, I just needed to run a query in HAT, right click on the tracked event and 'Save All Tracked Messages...' that then allows you to view the message bodies :)